# What shall i do with an old question without an answer?

Tags: discussion

I have some kind of urgent questions for me but without an answer.

What is the best way to renew the discussion except starting a bounty or its the only way?

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to link to a few of the questions you're talking about? Sometimes there are subtle ways to improve questions and make them more easy to answer

Comment: Here go a few:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31023/language-dependant-sidebars-vice-versa

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32486/what-is-the-most-simple-way-to-use-swf-file-as-a-field-and-output-it-within-disp

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/fivestar-vote-from-a-comment-is-not-included-in-average-vote-of-the-parent-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your questions are pretty clear, so there isn't much for improvement from that point of view.

What I would say is that they're all pretty niche, and people probably won't want to invest the large amount of time it will almost definitely take to try to answer them. So yes, I think bounties are the most appropriate solution here.

Just a note on the third question ( https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/fivestar-vote-from-a-comment-is-not-included-in-average-vote-of-the-parent-node ); the fact that you've reported that as an [issue on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1464392) automatically makes it off-topic for this site as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

Check for any potential duplicates or try to edit the old question by improving the quality or providing further details, if the question is interesting, it should easily renew the discussion.